# WCF POST The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details

Tags: c#, wcf

Ok, this is driving me nuts.

I've created a WCF service with four endpoints (three with GET and one with POST).

All three GET endpoints are working fine, but I'm unable to get the POST endpoint to work.

My interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFiscalCidadaoWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetConveniosByCoordinate/{latitude}/{longitude}")]
    TelaInicialEnvioViewModel GetConveniosByCoordinate(string latitude, string longitude);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "FazerDenuncia")]
    string FazerDenuncia(string model); // this is the one

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetConvenioById/{convenioId}")]
    ConvenioEnvioViewModel GetConvenioById(string convenioId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetDenunciaByUsuario/{usuarioId}")]
    List<DenunciaEnvioViewModel> GetDenunciaByUsuario(string usuarioId);
}
```

My service implementation:

```
 public string FazerDenuncia(string model)
 {            
     return "OK";
 }
```

Webconfig:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="FiscalCidadaoWCF.FiscalCidadaoWCF">
      <endpoint address="../FiscalCidadaoWCF.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"    contract="FiscalCidadaoWCF.IFiscalCidadaoWCF"behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
    </service>
  </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />        
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="webBehaviour">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

I'm testing using Postman and a client project using jQuery. Neither are working.

jQuery call:

```
 var data2 = "weba";

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://www.fiscalcidadao.site/FiscalCidadaoWCF.svc/FazerDenuncia',
    data: data2,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('working');
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert('shut up');
    },
});
```

I'm getting the error "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details". **But, if I try to call without parameters, the endpoint returns "Ok".**

So my question: What should I change in my project to make the POST endpoint to work passing a parameter? Or how can I find the "server logs" to see what's going on?

Comment: In your `ajax` call make `data: JSON.stringify(data2)` and add `contentType: "application/json"`.

Comment: With these changes it's returning '405 Method Not Allowed'

Comment: That's because you got past the original problem and now run into another one...:)  If you search for instance for `wcf 405 method not allowed` there's plenty of troubleshooting hints out there, including right here at SO.

Comment: @jstreet you've pointed me to the right direction. I've finally found what was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, post an answer explaining how you solved it so others can benefit from it.